# I want to display records from mysql between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from inward_outward where inward_date between '01-02-2016' and '21-02-2016'");
```

This query is yielding results in the months January and February, but my intention is that the query should return only results for February.

The query displays results like this[image]

[image: result of this query and i highlight the error in red symbol]

Comment: what datatype did you use for 'inward_date'?

Comment: This is not MYSQL DATE FORMAT its string

Comment: Date format should be YY-MM-DD

Comment: you require to change datatype of 'inward_date' to date, which deserves the input in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Comment: So store dates as dates, and then get back to us.

Comment: Don't know but read this will help u STR_TO_DATE(old_column, '%m/%d/%Y').... Else ALTER COLUMN

Comment: i use varchar(50)   i convert date when query is passing in to database i use this code for that       $date="";
            $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
            $date = date('d-m-Y', $date);

Answer (score 1):

As the date is a varchar ( why? ) you'll need to convert it to a date before using any comparison logic.

You could convert all of these dates to the proper format and be done with it - so long as in future you enter dates in the correct format and not some silly varchar reverse form ~ it would make life easier in the long term.

```
set @sd='21-01-2016';
set @ed='21-02-2016';

select * from `inward_outward` 
where date_format( str_to_date( `inward_date`, '%d-%m-%Y' ), '%Y-%m-%d' )
between 
    date_format( str_to_date( @sd, '%d-%m-%Y' ), '%Y-%m-%d' )
        and 
    date_format( str_to_date( @ed, '%d-%m-%Y' ), '%Y-%m-%d' )
```

Comment: it till display same i use data type for inward_date is varchar any problem with this data type

Comment: oh - the dates used in the between statement are also in the wrong format too.